# Calculate based on user input of quantity

Tags: php, jquery

I want to calculate the production cost of making a product based on user input. I have this input field for user to input the quantity they want.

`Quantity:
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" required>`

I have this code to echo the total material cost.

```
<p align="left">Total Material Cost: <u>$<?php echo $row['SUM(material_price*quantity)']; ?> </u> </p>
```

How do I link the quantity based on user input to the material cost?

Like if user input 3, I would like the total material cost * 3

---

This is my database for material

material_master_id |material_name | quantity
1                  |table top     | 1
2                  |table legs    | 4

I would like to echo the quantity for id 1 and 2 respectively.

this is my code
`<p align="left">Total quantity of Table Tops: <?php echo $row['quantity']; $material_master_id=="1" ;?></p>`

but it says Undefined index: quantity. How do I solve it?

Comment: Please use jQuery ajax for get dynamic  quantity calculation.

Comment: Is it possible to do with PHP code? I do not know how jQuery ajax works.

Comment: are you wanting to do this on form post using php, or dynamically as they change `quantity` on client side using javascript?

Comment: @Janice yes it is possible on form submit. do we able to refresh page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="100" required />
<input type="hidden" name="material_price" id="material_price" value="<?php echo $row['material_price'] ?>" />
<p align="left" class="calculate_result"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#quantity").focusout(function() {
            var calculate_result = parseInt($(this).val())*parseInt($("#material_price").val());
            $(".calculate_result").html(calculate_result);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**OR**

Below code is useful if you don't want to use jQuery:

```
<?php if($_POST['submit_me']!="") { 
//use query to get the $row (for getting material_price)
?>
<p align="left">Total Material Cost: <u>$<?php echo row['material_price']*$_POST['quantity']; ?> </u> </p>
<?php } ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="100" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit_me" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: As the OP did not tag `jQuery`, and even stated [*I do not know how jQuery ajax works*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605230/calculate-based-on-user-input-of-quantity#comment56956033_34605230), it might be helpful to also describe/show how to include the jQuery library.

Comment: @Sean He/She added that comment after i submitted my answer..... So i didn't show that...

Comment: The comment may have been after you posted, but no where in the OP's question did they mention javascript/jQuery. It is okay to suggest jQuery, but your answer should be more than just `Try like below:` as you need to explain why using this code would work for what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Thank you, it works. 

 I have another question. I would like to echo the quantity for table top and legs respectively. right now this is my code which only echo the number 1. `<p align="left">Total quantity of Table Tops: <?php echo $quantity; ?></p> <p align="left">Total quantity of Table Legs: <?php echo $quantity; ?></p>` How do I echo for Table Top should be 1, Legs should be 4?

[View Table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dCTAt.png)

Comment: @Janice Not getting you exactly, can you edit your query in question at the end...

Comment: @Janice Write full code not just the line of code, please add your full code with query and loop etc....

Answer (score 0):

Please use Jquery to calculate data. and show the result through Jquery.

Comment: Please write in comment if you want to give suggestion